# UEFI Boot options menu at every boot : how to make it work?

Tags: boot, multi-boot, uefi, bootloader, asus

I have a Asus Strix X99 gaming motherboard with a I7-6800K CPU

https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-X99-GAMING/

I have two M.2 NVME SSDs attached:

1. SSD N°1 = Samsung SM951 512G M.2 PCIe 3.0 x4 AHCI => Windows 10 LTSB 2016
2. SSD N°2 = Samsung PM961 1TB  M.2 PCIe 3.2 x4 NVMe => Windows 10 LTSC 2019

I would like to be able to choose from which one to boot at every startup of the machine.

For now, I have to go into Asus UEFI bios at every startup, go into "boot options" and choose which drive / bootloader I want to launch... kind of tedious.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[EasyUEFI](https://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) may helpful in Windows, that's a GUI tool also allows command line access in its paid version, which may be an option for you.

Comment: There is also Refind [link](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) but I have trouble anderstanding who either EasyUEFI and Refind are able to place themselves at the very start of boot..